# VK API | Отлавливание сообщений от сообщества

Tags: php, вконтакте

Имеется сообщество, у меня же есть к нему всё управление. Допустим к сообществу подключён бот и он отправляет юзерам сообщения. Так вот, как мне поймать и обработать сообщение которое он отправил пользователю? Ну точнее как ловить сообщения что отправила группа собеседнику. PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант перейти в Настройки группы -> Работа с API -> Callback API -> Типы событий и включить "исходящие сообщения"